# pushwoosh blackberry html5 integration

Tags: html, blackberry, pushwoosh

am creating an app using html5 and compiling with phonegap, and so i am trying to integrate and use the pushwoosh plugin for blackberry webworks so i can send and receive notifications, but am stuck up somewhere, from the tutorial on their site

"http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/blackberry/blackberry-additional-platforms/blackberry-html5-webworks-push-notification-sdk/"

i dont know where to include this,

"PushWoosh.appCode = '6C3BE-1B140';"

can someone please shed more light on this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pushwoosh.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>PushWoosh.appCode = 'YOUR_PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID';</script>
 
<script src="master.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Wrap Pushwoosh.appCode with script tag.

Comment: Thanks, iv done dat but am getting this error onload of my app "result of expression : blackberry.push undefined, please wats d course of dis thanks

Comment: Are you trying this on a simulator or a real device? For example Ripple does not support push at all.

Comment: So wat could I have done wrong, is theere any workin sample of this implementation for blackberry